# Client endpoint configuration '*' was not found in 1 Endpoints, WCF, Mono

Tags: c#, linux, wcf, mono, wcf-endpoint

Hej guys,

i'm trying to access a webservice hosted on a virtual machine (Windows 7) from my Ubuntu Host using Mono.

I can import the wdsl file and generate the service reference. I copied the App.config from an other working client accessing the webservice correctly.

When i try to connect to the webservice using
    using System;

```
namespace MonoTest
{
class MainClass
{
    public static void Main (string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine ("Hello World!");
        TestServer.Service1Client client = new TestServer.Service1Client("Test");
        Console.WriteLine(client.GetData(12));
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
}
```

I get an error:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Client endpoint configuration 'Test' was not found in 1 endpoints.
  at System.ServiceModel.ChannelFactory.ApplyConfiguration (System.String endpointConfig) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.ServiceModel.ChannelFactory.InitializeEndpoint (System.String endpointConfigurationName, System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress remoteAddress) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.ServiceModel.ChannelFactory`1[MonoTest.TestServer.IService1]..ctor (System.String endpointConfigurationName, System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress remoteAddress) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.ServiceModel.ClientBase`1[MonoTest.TestServer.IService1].Initialize (System.ServiceModel.InstanceContext instance, System.String endpointConfigurationName, System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress remoteAddress) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.ServiceModel.ClientBase`1[MonoTest.TestServer.IService1]..ctor (System.ServiceModel.InstanceContext instance, System.String endpointConfigurationName) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.ServiceModel.ClientBase`1[MonoTest.TestServer.IService1]..ctor (System.String endpointConfigurationName) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at MonoTest.TestServer.Service1Client..ctor (System.String endpointConfigurationName) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at MonoTest.MainClass.Main (System.String[] args) [0x0000a] in /home/***/WebserviceTest/MonoTest/MonoTest/Main.cs:11
```

My App.config file looks like the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <wsHttpBinding>
                <binding name="WSHttpBinding_IService1" />
            </wsHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint name="Test"
                address="http://192.168.178.34:8732/Design_Time_Addresses/TestServer/Service1/"
                binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_IService1"
                contract="ServiceReference1.IService1" >
                <identity>
                    <dns value="localhost" />
                </identity>
            </endpoint>
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Has anyone made this working using Linux?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Mono's WSDL import tool does not support automatic configuration generation yet, you need to manually configure your endpoints in your `app.config`.

The error that you're seeing here means that WCF can't find the endpoint configuration section.

**The detailed, technical reason for the problem**

You are getting this because Visual Studio and Mono have a different, incompatible way of referencing the configuration section.

When adding a Service Reference in Visual Studio, it automatically creates and updates the corresponding entries in your `app.config`.  The "contract name" that's in the generated `<endpoint ... contract="contract name">` is not necessarily the fully qualified name of the data contract class in the generated `Reference.cs`.

Instead, Visual Studio emits

```
    [ServiceContractAttribute(ConfigurationName="contract name")]
    public interface YourContract {
            ....
    }
```

The `ConfigurationName` is the same as in the `<endpoint ... contract="...">` element, that's how WCF finds the endpoint configuration.

In Mono, since we don't support config file generation yet, we emit

```
    [ServiceContractAttribute]
    public interface YourContract {
            ....
    }
```

Without the `ConfigurationName` argument, the default is the fully qualified name of that interface.

**How to fix your problem**

To get this to work, you need to edit your `app.config` file and use the fully qualified name of your service contract interface in the `<endpoint ... contract="...">` element.

In your case, changing `contract="ServiceReference1.IService1"` into `contract="TestServer.IService1"` should do it.

Otherwise, look into the generated `Reference.cs`, search for an interface with a `[ServiceContractAttribute]` and which C# namespace it is in.

Answer (score 0):

Mono WCF is partial implemetation of dotnet WCF, hence few feature and binding are unsupported :

There is also a article which says

Components with no plan to support

> **WSHttpBinding** and its dependencies
>       TransactionFlow
>       ReliableSession

Please see : 
http://www.mono-project.com/WCF_Development

Comment: Thanks, the problem is actually that old that I'm not looking for a solution anymore. But thanks to your help!