# Correctly set up service reference in Mono

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, web-services, mono

I can figure out how to correctly set up a service reference generated from wsdl in mono. I precompile my application in visual studio where the webservice is generated automatically. As i tried to solve this by myself i came across this post : [Client endpoint configuration '*' was not found in 1 Endpoints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10939445/client-endpoint-configuration-was-not-found-in-1-endpoints-wcf-mono)

But i was not able to understand how to change the code for me. The generated code in VS looks like this for me:

```
    namespace manager.ServiceNamespace {        

        [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel", "4.0.0.0")]
        [System.ServiceModel.ServiceContractAttribute(Namespace="urn:DefaultNamespace", ConfigurationName="ServiceNamespace.BindingInterface")]
        public interface BindingInterface { ... }
    }
```

While the generated app.config looks like this:

```
<configuration>
<startup> 
<supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5"/></startup>
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
          <binding name="BindingInterface" allowCookies="true" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647">
            <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"/>
          </binding>
        </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="http://example.com/webservice/soap/1.0/" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BindingInterface" contract="ServiceNamespace.BindingInterface" name="SomeName"/>
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

The Exception thrown by Mono says that:

```
Client endpoint configuration '*' was not found in 0 endpoints.
```

How can i corretly tell mono the right configuration?

Comment: Hi! Did you fix this problem?